# How to disable ant in eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, ant, pydev

I am new to Python and only installed Eclipse + Pydev as the autoformatting possibilities would help me with  the annoyingly stringent indentation rules of Python, which weren't being caught by Geany for example. (These have cost me HOURS of futile searching for even very simple intentaion problems).

I don't need Java or Jython (yet), so how do I disable the interference from Ant at Run time?

Or is there another IDE with autoformatting that doesn't need Java support that would be better suited?

Comment: In what way does Ant interfere? It is pretty integral to Eclipse so I doubt that it can be disabled.

Comment: What is exactly the behavior you would want to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

Ant doesn't run in Eclipse at runtime unless you have an Ant builder on the project.  (it might be something else causing whatever behavior is bothering you.)  That said, Eclipse is a heavy IDE if you only want it for the formatting help.  If you are using other features like debugging, PyDev is helpful.

You might consider a lightweight IDE.  [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) has a [Python plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net).

Comment: You are right,  it's too heavy for my needs. However, PyDev is not available for Linux, only as a plugin for Eclipse. As I said earlier,for the moment (pre-Java),  I only need a lightweight IDE like Geany, but need the formatting support of PyDev

Comment: Did you look at NotePad++ as I suggested?